# Attribute Error while using PyQtgraph libraries in my python code

Tags: python, spyder, attributeerror, pyqtgraph

I'm running a code from github site and it has this error ( last lines) :

```
    File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\opengl\GLViewWidget.py", line 152, in viewMatrix
    tr.translate(-center.x(), -center.y(), -center.z())

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'
```

I found that the error is related to pyqtgraph libraries and i didn't change their files
just install the last versions of PyOpenGl and PyQtGraph in spyder

can you please help me in this error?

Answer (score 0):

We need more information,
The problem seems to be related to the fact that center is an int but you use it as an object with attributs

Can we see center's initialization ?

Comment: this is PyQtGraph file : i didn'tnt change it

Answer (score 0):

the GlViewWidget.py file :

```
from ..Qt import QtCore, QtGui, QtOpenGL, QT_LIB
from OpenGL.GL import *
import OpenGL.GL.framebufferobjects as glfbo
import numpy as np
from .. import Vector
from .. import functions as fn

##Vector = QtGui.QVector3D

ShareWidget = None

class GLViewWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
    """
    Basic widget for displaying 3D data
        - Rotation/scale controls
        - Axis/grid display
        - Export options


    High-DPI displays: Qt5 should automatically detect the correct resolution.
    For Qt4, specify the ``devicePixelRatio`` argument when initializing the
    widget (usually this value is 1-2).
    """
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None, devicePixelRatio=None):
        global ShareWidget

        if ShareWidget is None:
            ## create a dummy widget to allow sharing objects (textures, shaders, etc) between views
            ShareWidget = QtOpenGL.QGLWidget()
            
        QtOpenGL.QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent, ShareWidget)
        
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        
        self.opts = {
            'center': Vector(0,0,0),  ## will always appear at the center of the widget
            'distance': 10.0,         ## distance of camera from center
            'fov':  60,               ## horizontal field of view in degrees
            'elevation':  30,         ## camera's angle of elevation in degrees
            'azimuth': 45,            ## camera's azimuthal angle in degrees 
                                      ## (rotation around z-axis 0 points along x-axis)
            'viewport': None,         ## glViewport params; None == whole widget
            'devicePixelRatio': devicePixelRatio,
        }
        self.setBackgroundColor('k')
        self.items = []
        self.noRepeatKeys = [QtCore.Qt.Key_Right, QtCore.Qt.Key_Left, QtCore.Qt.Key_Up, QtCore.Qt.Key_Down, QtCore.Qt.Key_PageUp, QtCore.Qt.Key_PageDown]
        self.keysPressed = {}
        self.keyTimer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.keyTimer.timeout.connect(self.evalKeyState)
        
        self.makeCurrent()

    def addItem(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
        if hasattr(item, 'initializeGL'):
            self.makeCurrent()
            try:
                item.initializeGL()
            except:
                self.checkOpenGLVersion('Error while adding item %s to GLViewWidget.' % str(item))
                
        item._setView(self)
        #print "set view", item, self, item.view()
        self.update()
        
    def removeItem(self, item):
        self.items.remove(item)
        item._setView(None)
        self.update()
        
        
    def initializeGL(self):
        self.resizeGL(self.width(), self.height())
        
    def setBackgroundColor(self, *args, **kwds):
        """
        Set the background color of the widget. Accepts the same arguments as
        pg.mkColor() and pg.glColor().
        """
        self.opts['bgcolor'] = fn.glColor(*args, **kwds)
        self.update()
        
    def getViewport(self):
        vp = self.opts['viewport']
        dpr = self.devicePixelRatio()
        if vp is None:
            return (0, 0, int(self.width() * dpr), int(self.height() * dpr))
        else:
            return tuple([int(x * dpr) for x in vp])
        
    def devicePixelRatio(self):
        dpr = self.opts['devicePixelRatio']
        if dpr is not None:
            return dpr
        
        if hasattr(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget, 'devicePixelRatio'):
            return QtOpenGL.QGLWidget.devicePixelRatio(self)
        else:
            return 1.0
        
    def resizeGL(self, w, h):
        pass
        #glViewport(*self.getViewport())
        #self.update()

    def setProjection(self, region=None):
        m = self.projectionMatrix(region)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        a = np.array(m.copyDataTo()).reshape((4,4))
        glMultMatrixf(a.transpose())

    def projectionMatrix(self, region=None):
        if region is None:
            dpr = self.devicePixelRatio()
            region = (0, 0, self.width() * dpr, self.height() * dpr)
        
        x0, y0, w, h = self.getViewport()
        dist = self.opts['distance']
        fov = self.opts['fov']
        nearClip = dist * 0.001
        farClip = dist * 1000.

        r = nearClip * np.tan(fov * 0.5 * np.pi / 180.)
        t = r * h / w

        ## Note that X0 and width in these equations must be the values used in viewport
        left  = r * ((region[0]-x0) * (2.0/w) - 1)
        right = r * ((region[0]+region[2]-x0) * (2.0/w) - 1)
        bottom = t * ((region[1]-y0) * (2.0/h) - 1)
        top    = t * ((region[1]+region[3]-y0) * (2.0/h) - 1)

        tr = QtGui.QMatrix4x4()
        tr.frustum(left, right, bottom, top, nearClip, farClip)
        return tr
        
    def setModelview(self):
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        m = self.viewMatrix()
        a = np.array(m.copyDataTo()).reshape((4,4))
        glMultMatrixf(a.transpose())
        
    def viewMatrix(self):
        tr = QtGui.QMatrix4x4()
        tr.translate( 0.0, 0.0, -self.opts['distance'])
        tr.rotate(self.opts['elevation']-90, 1, 0, 0)
        tr.rotate(self.opts['azimuth']+90, 0, 0, -1)
        center = self.opts['center']
        tr.translate(-center.x(), -center.y(), -center.z())
        return tr

    def itemsAt(self, region=None):
        """
        Return a list of the items displayed in the region (x, y, w, h)
        relative to the widget.        
        """
        region = (region[0], self.height()-(region[1]+region[3]), region[2], region[3])
        
        #buf = np.zeros(100000, dtype=np.uint)
        buf = glSelectBuffer(100000)
        try:
            glRenderMode(GL_SELECT)
            glInitNames()
            glPushName(0)
            self._itemNames = {}
            self.paintGL(region=region, useItemNames=True)
            
        finally:
            hits = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER)
            
        items = [(h.near, h.names[0]) for h in hits]
        items.sort(key=lambda i: i[0])
        return [self._itemNames[i[1]] for i in items]
    
    def paintGL(self, region=None, viewport=None, useItemNames=False):
        """
        viewport specifies the arguments to glViewport. If None, then we use self.opts['viewport']
        region specifies the sub-region of self.opts['viewport'] that should be rendered.
        Note that we may use viewport != self.opts['viewport'] when exporting.
        """
        if viewport is None:
            glViewport(*self.getViewport())
        else:
            glViewport(*viewport)
        self.setProjection(region=region)
        self.setModelview()
        bgcolor = self.opts['bgcolor']
        glClearColor(*bgcolor)
        glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT )
        self.drawItemTree(useItemNames=useItemNames)
        
    def drawItemTree(self, item=None, useItemNames=False):
        if item is None:
            items = [x for x in self.items if x.parentItem() is None]
        else:
            items = item.childItems()
            items.append(item)
        items.sort(key=lambda a: a.depthValue())
        for i in items:
            if not i.visible():
                continue
            if i is item:
                try:
                    glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS)
                    if useItemNames:
                        glLoadName(i._id)
                        self._itemNames[i._id] = i
                    i.paint()
                except:
                    from .. import debug
                    debug.printExc()
                    msg = "Error while drawing item %s." % str(item)
                    ver = glGetString(GL_VERSION)
                    if ver is not None:
                        ver = ver.split()[0]
                        if int(ver.split(b'.')[0]) < 2:
                            print(msg + " The original exception is printed above; however, pyqtgraph requires OpenGL version 2.0 or greater for many of its 3D features and your OpenGL version is %s. Installing updated display drivers may resolve this issue." % ver)
                        else:
                            print(msg)
                    
                finally:
                    glPopAttrib()
            else:
                glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
                glPushMatrix()
                try:
                    tr = i.transform()
                    a = np.array(tr.copyDataTo()).reshape((4,4))
                    glMultMatrixf(a.transpose())
                    self.drawItemTree(i, useItemNames=useItemNames)
                finally:
                    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
                    glPopMatrix()
            
    def setCameraPosition(self, pos=None, distance=None, elevation=None, azimuth=None):
        if pos is not None:
            self.opts['center'] = pos
        if distance is not None:
            self.opts['distance'] = distance
        if elevation is not None:
            self.opts['elevation'] = elevation
        if azimuth is not None:
            self.opts['azimuth'] = azimuth
        self.update()
        
    def cameraPosition(self):
        """Return current position of camera based on center, dist, elevation, and azimuth"""
        center = self.opts['center']
        dist = self.opts['distance']
        elev = self.opts['elevation'] * np.pi/180.
        azim = self.opts['azimuth'] * np.pi/180.
        
        pos = Vector(
            center.x() + dist * np.cos(elev) * np.cos(azim),
            center.y() + dist * np.cos(elev) * np.sin(azim),
            center.z() + dist * np.sin(elev)
        )
        
        return pos

    def orbit(self, azim, elev):
        """Orbits the camera around the center position. *azim* and *elev* are given in degrees."""
        self.opts['azimuth'] += azim
        self.opts['elevation'] = np.clip(self.opts['elevation'] + elev, -90, 90)
        self.update()
        
    def pan(self, dx, dy, dz, relative='global'):
        """
        Moves the center (look-at) position while holding the camera in place. 
        
        ==============  =======================================================
        **Arguments:**
        *dx*            Distance to pan in x direction
        *dy*            Distance to pan in y direction
        *dx*            Distance to pan in z direction
        *relative*      String that determines the direction of dx,dy,dz. 
                        If "global", then the global coordinate system is used.
                        If "view", then the z axis is aligned with the view
                        direction, and x and y axes are inthe plane of the
                        view: +x points right, +y points up. 
                        If "view-upright", then x is in the global xy plane and
                        points to the right side of the view, y is in the
                        global xy plane and orthogonal to x, and z points in
                        the global z direction.
        ==============  =======================================================
        
        Distances are scaled roughly such that a value of 1.0 moves
        by one pixel on screen.
        
        Prior to version 0.11, *relative* was expected to be either True (x-aligned) or
        False (global). These values are deprecated but still recognized.
        """
        # for backward compatibility:
        relative = {True: "view-upright", False: "global"}.get(relative, relative)
        
        if relative == 'global':
            self.opts['center'] += QtGui.QVector3D(dx, dy, dz)
        elif relative == 'view-upright':
            cPos = self.cameraPosition()
            cVec = self.opts['center'] - cPos
            dist = cVec.length()  ## distance from camera to center
            xDist = dist * 2. * np.tan(0.5 * self.opts['fov'] * np.pi / 180.)  ## approx. width of view at distance of center point
            xScale = xDist / self.width()
            zVec = QtGui.QVector3D(0,0,1)
            xVec = QtGui.QVector3D.crossProduct(zVec, cVec).normalized()
            yVec = QtGui.QVector3D.crossProduct(xVec, zVec).normalized()
            self.opts['center'] = self.opts['center'] + xVec * xScale * dx + yVec * xScale * dy + zVec * xScale * dz
        elif relative == 'view':
            # pan in plane of camera
            elev = np.radians(self.opts['elevation'])
            azim = np.radians(self.opts['azimuth'])
            fov = np.radians(self.opts['fov'])
            dist = (self.opts['center'] - self.cameraPosition()).length()
            fov_factor = np.tan(fov / 2) * 2
            scale_factor = dist * fov_factor / self.width()
            z = scale_factor * np.cos(elev) * dy
            x = scale_factor * (np.sin(azim) * dx - np.sin(elev) * np.cos(azim) * dy)
            y = scale_factor * (np.cos(azim) * dx + np.sin(elev) * np.sin(azim) * dy)
            self.opts['center'] += QtGui.QVector3D(x, -y, z)
        else:
            raise ValueError("relative argument must be global, view, or view-upright")
        
        self.update()
        
    def pixelSize(self, pos):
        """
        Return the approximate size of a screen pixel at the location pos
        Pos may be a Vector or an (N,3) array of locations
        """
        cam = self.cameraPosition()
        if isinstance(pos, np.ndarray):
            cam = np.array(cam).reshape((1,)*(pos.ndim-1)+(3,))
            dist = ((pos-cam)**2).sum(axis=-1)**0.5
        else:
            dist = (pos-cam).length()
        xDist = dist * 2. * np.tan(0.5 * self.opts['fov'] * np.pi / 180.)
        return xDist / self.width()
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        self.mousePos = ev.pos()
        
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, ev):
        diff = ev.pos() - self.mousePos
        self.mousePos = ev.pos()
        
        if ev.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            if (ev.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier):
                self.pan(diff.x(), diff.y(), 0, relative='view')
            else:
                self.orbit(-diff.x(), diff.y())
        elif ev.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.MidButton:
            if (ev.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier):
                self.pan(diff.x(), 0, diff.y(), relative='view-upright')
            else:
                self.pan(diff.x(), diff.y(), 0, relative='view-upright')
        
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, ev):
        pass
        # Example item selection code:
        #region = (ev.pos().x()-5, ev.pos().y()-5, 10, 10)
        #print(self.itemsAt(region))
        
        ## debugging code: draw the picking region
        #glViewport(*self.getViewport())
        #glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT )
        #region = (region[0], self.height()-(region[1]+region[3]), region[2], region[3])
        #self.paintGL(region=region)
        #self.swapBuffers()
        
        
    def wheelEvent(self, ev):
        delta = 0
        if QT_LIB in ['PyQt4', 'PySide']:
            delta = ev.delta()
        else:
            delta = ev.angleDelta().x()
            if delta == 0:
                delta = ev.angleDelta().y()
        if (ev.modifiers() & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier):
            self.opts['fov'] *= 0.999**delta
        else:
            self.opts['distance'] *= 0.999**delta
        self.update()

    def keyPressEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.key() in self.noRepeatKeys:
            ev.accept()
            if ev.isAutoRepeat():
                return
            self.keysPressed[ev.key()] = 1
            self.evalKeyState()
      
    def keyReleaseEvent(self, ev):
        if ev.key() in self.noRepeatKeys:
            ev.accept()
            if ev.isAutoRepeat():
                return
            try:
                del self.keysPressed[ev.key()]
            except:
                self.keysPressed = {}
            self.evalKeyState()
        
    def evalKeyState(self):
        speed = 2.0
        if len(self.keysPressed) > 0:
            for key in self.keysPressed:
                if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:
                    self.orbit(azim=-speed, elev=0)
                elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:
                    self.orbit(azim=speed, elev=0)
                elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
                    self.orbit(azim=0, elev=-speed)
                elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
                    self.orbit(azim=0, elev=speed)
                elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_PageUp:
                    pass
                elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_PageDown:
                    pass
                self.keyTimer.start(16)
        else:
            self.keyTimer.stop()

    def checkOpenGLVersion(self, msg):
        ## Only to be called from within exception handler.
        ver = glGetString(GL_VERSION).split()[0]
        if int(ver.split(b'.')[0]) < 2:
            from .. import debug
            debug.printExc()
            raise Exception(msg + " The original exception is printed above; however, pyqtgraph requires OpenGL version 2.0 or greater for many of its 3D features and your OpenGL version is %s. Installing updated display drivers may resolve this issue." % ver)
        else:
            raise
            
    def readQImage(self):
        """
        Read the current buffer pixels out as a QImage.
        """
        w = self.width()
        h = self.height()
        self.repaint()
        pixels = np.empty((h, w, 4), dtype=np.ubyte)
        pixels[:] = 128
        pixels[...,0] = 50
        pixels[...,3] = 255
        
        glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels)
        
        # swap B,R channels for Qt
        tmp = pixels[...,0].copy()
        pixels[...,0] = pixels[...,2]
        pixels[...,2] = tmp
        pixels = pixels[::-1] # flip vertical
        
        img = fn.makeQImage(pixels, transpose=False)
        return img
        
    def renderToArray(self, size, format=GL_BGRA, type=GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureSize=1024, padding=256):
        w,h = map(int, size)
        
        self.makeCurrent()
        tex = None
        fb = None
        try:
            output = np.empty((w, h, 4), dtype=np.ubyte)
            fb = glfbo.glGenFramebuffers(1)
            glfbo.glBindFramebuffer(glfbo.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb )
            
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
            tex = glGenTextures(1)
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex)
            texwidth = textureSize
            data = np.zeros((texwidth,texwidth,4), dtype=np.ubyte)
            
            ## Test texture dimensions first
            glTexImage2D(GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texwidth, texwidth, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, None)
            if glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH) == 0:
                raise Exception("OpenGL failed to create 2D texture (%dx%d); too large for this hardware." % shape[:2])
            ## create teture
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texwidth, texwidth, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data.transpose((1,0,2)))
            
            self.opts['viewport'] = (0, 0, w, h)  # viewport is the complete image; this ensures that paintGL(region=...) 
                                                  # is interpreted correctly.
            p2 = 2 * padding
            for x in range(-padding, w-padding, texwidth-p2):
                for y in range(-padding, h-padding, texwidth-p2):
                    x2 = min(x+texwidth, w+padding)
                    y2 = min(y+texwidth, h+padding)
                    w2 = x2-x
                    h2 = y2-y
                    
                    ## render to texture
                    glfbo.glFramebufferTexture2D(glfbo.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, glfbo.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0)
                    
                    self.paintGL(region=(x, h-y-h2, w2, h2), viewport=(0, 0, w2, h2))  # only render sub-region
                    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex) # fixes issue #366
                    
                    ## read texture back to array
                    data = glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, type)
                    data = np.fromstring(data, dtype=np.ubyte).reshape(texwidth,texwidth,4).transpose(1,0,2)[:, ::-1]
                    output[x+padding:x2-padding, y+padding:y2-padding] = data[padding:w2-padding, -(h2-padding):-padding]
                    
        finally:
            self.opts['viewport'] = None
            glfbo.glBindFramebuffer(glfbo.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
            if tex is not None:
                glDeleteTextures([tex])
            if fb is not None:
                glfbo.glDeleteFramebuffers([fb])
            
        return output
```

Comment: This section is for answers.  Don't post clarifying/additional information regarding your question here; instead, edit your original question and include it there.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you are setting the center to be an int. `setCameraPosition`, maybe? It needs to be a `Vector` object, instead.